# Plugin to select the custom image crop area

Tags: images, cropping

I've defined the custom thumbnail sizes and set it up in a mu-plugins script.

```
<?php
function penge_features() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('Homepage Carousel', 1210, 540, true); // new
    add_image_size('Article Hero', 800, 267, true); // new
    add_image_size('Landing Page Hero', 1210, 300, true); // new
    add_image_size('1/3 Tile', 390, 350, true); // new
    add_image_size('1/2 Tile Desktop', 290, 350, array('center', 'center' )); // new - Home page, image required
    add_image_size('1/2 Tile Tablet', 188, 350, array('center', 'center' )); // new - Home page, on some tablets
    add_image_size('tyle', 350, 350, array('center', 'center' )); // Current - tile image size, Home page and sub pages
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'penge_features');

?>
```

The image's crop version/variation is specified programmatically in a template so I'm not talking about images being inserted into a body of a post within Gutenberg.

How can I manually specify which area of the picture is being cropped to for each thumbnail size. Not programmatically but so that when an admin uploads a photo, they can specify the area of photo for to be cropped for one of the thumbnail sizes specified above?

Comment: So you'd like uploading an image to offer you select-crop dialogs for every distinct aspect ratio in your list? That sounds possible but a lot of work I'd think: the dialog would be the hard part but you'd then need to hook into the thumbnail generation code to make sure it uses the crop areas selected and feed that into GD or ImageMagick as appropriate.

Comment: There was a plugin where you visually selected the crop area but it has recently stopped working it was last updated ages ago. My original question was asking for an alternative plugin recommendation to do the job - but plugin recommendations are out of this site's scope and my question was closed so I rephrased it. I'm not really interested in coding it from scratch. I thought there'd be a ready solution for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your best bet might be to help fix up the plugin then so it works again, but I don't know how complicated that would be. There [are a few other interested people on GitHub](https://github.com/tomaszsita/wp-manual-image-crop/issues/69) and the [mcaskill](https://github.com/mcaskill/wp-manual-image-crop) and the [tpow](https://github.com/tpow/wp-manual-image-crop) forks look the most active.

Comment: When you say recently stopped working, it could be because WP 5.6 switched to jQuery 3. I'd try replacing the jQuery plugins with newer jQuery 3-compatible versions as a first step (if they are still maintained!).